# VBA Userform textbox remembering the last entry

Tags: vba, textbox, userform

I am new to VBA and I have a question. I have created a userform in excel. So, my question is that I want to enter values in the textbox and submit, the next time I launch the userform, it remembers the last entry in the userform. So, for example, I have textbox called facility. I enter in value UHN for the first time. Once I have closed the userform. Then I open the userform again, the value UHN is already filled in so the user does not need to type it again. So, the user form remembers the last entry in the textbox.

Thank you in advance!

My vba code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub AddlistButton_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long

wsmenu.Activate

emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

Me.Hide

wsfilms.Select

'Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
'Add facility name
ActiveCell.Value = FacilityBox
'Add service area
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ServiceAreaBox
'Add date
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = DateBox
'Add time
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = TimeBox.Value
'Add room
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = RoomBox.Value

'Briefing Question 1
If Yes1.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "No"
End If
'Timeout Question 1
If Yes2.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "No"
End If
If Yes3.Value = True Then
'Debriefing Question 1
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "No"
End If
'Comment 1
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = Comment1.Value

'Briefing Question 2
If Yes4.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = "No"
End If
'Timeout Question 2
If Yes5.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = "No"
End If
'Debriefing Question 2
If Yes6.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = "No"
End If
'Comment 2
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).Value = Comment2.Value

'Briefing Question 3
If Yes7.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Value = "No"
End If
'Timeout Question 3
If Yes8.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Value = "No"
End If
'Debriefing Question 3
If Yes9.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15).Value = "No"
End If
'Comment 3
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16).Value = Comment3.Value

'Briefing Question 4
If Yes10.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17).Value = "No"
End If
'Timeout Question 4
If Yes11.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18).Value = "No"
End If
'Debriefing Question 4
If Yes12.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 19).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 19).Value = "No"
End If
'Comment 4
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20).Value = Comment4.Value

'Briefing Question 5
If Yes13.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21).Value = "No"
End If
'Timeout Question 5
If Yes14.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 22).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 22).Value = "No"
End If
'Debriefing Question 5
If Yes15.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23).Value = "No"
End If
'Comment 5
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24).Value = Comment5.Value

'Briefing Question 6
If Yes16.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 25).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 25).Value = "No"
End If
'Timeout Question 6
If Yes17.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26).Value = "No"
End If
'Debriefing Question 6
If Yes18.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 27).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 27).Value = "No"
End If
'Comment 6
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 28).Value = Comment6.Value

'Briefing Question 7
If Yes19.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 29).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 29).Value = "No"
End If
'Timeout Question 7
If Yes20.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 30).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 30).Value = "No"
End If
'Debriefing Question 7
If Yes21.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 31).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 31).Value = "No"
End If
'Comment 7
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 32).Value = Comment7.Value

'Additional Question 8
If Yes22.Value = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 33).Value = "Yes"
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 33).Value = "No"
End If
'Comment 8
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 34).Value = comment8.Value
'Completed by
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 35).Value = comment9.Value

MsgBox " Data was successfully added to row " & ActiveCell.Row
Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
Me.Hide
'Unload FilmDetails
Unload Me
End Sub



Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

TimeBox.Text = Format(Time, "hh:mm AM/PM")
DateBox.Text = Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy")
With ServiceAreaBox
.AddItem "Anaesthesiology"
.AddItem "Cardiac"
.AddItem "Endoscopy"
.AddItem "General"
.AddItem "Gynaecologic"
.AddItem "Neurosurgery"
.AddItem "Obstetrics"
.AddItem "Oncology"
.AddItem "Ophthalmic"
.AddItem "Oral and Maxillofacial and Dentistry"
.AddItem "Orthopaedic"
.AddItem "Otolaryngic (ENT)"
.AddItem "Plastic and Reconstructive"
.AddItem "Thoracic"
.AddItem "Transplant"
.AddItem "Urologic"
.AddItem "Vascular"
.AddItem "All Other "
End With


 End Sub

 Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
 wsmenu.Select
 End Sub

 Private Sub Yes1_Click()

 End Sub
```

Comment: Consider storing the values somewhere. Either the registry or a text file. Have a look at GetSetting and SaveSetting: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/savesetting-statement?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You could also consider storing the data in a range on a spreadsheet of your workbook. Something like `Range.Cells(1,1).value = Me.TextBox1.text`. When the userform is loaded, the initialize function can set the textbox value to the cell value, someting like `Me.TextBox1.Text = Range.Cells(1,1).Value`. I don't have office installed on this PC yet, so I haven't tested sorry!